# PHP include is re-run on AJAX Request. Is this normal behavior?

Tags: php, ajax, firefox

I have a header.inc.php, the actual php web page and a footer.inc.php. The actual page also uses an include that logs activity to database. So simplified my page looks like this:

```
<?php
    require_once 'header.inc.php';
    require_once 'insertSearchLog.inc.php';
?>
<!--HTML and JavaScript for AJAX-->
<?php
    require_once 'footer.inc.php';
?>
```

AJAX is done using JQuery with JQuery plugin datatables.

The issue is that the include insertSearchLog.inc.php is executed once for every row in the displayed datatable which makes no sense to me? isn't the point of AJAX not to reload the whole page?
How can I prevent this behavior?

Additonal comment: Seems to be a FireFox issue as with IE8 this problem does not occur!

EDIT:

to avoid the issue I added a check prior to inserting into log:

```
$searchString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['lastQueryString'])
        || $searchString != $_SESSION['lastQueryString']) {

    // insert into log snipped

    $_SESSION['lastQueryString'] = $searchString;
}
```

But the original question remains as I would find it very puzzling if this is default firefox behavior.

EDIT 2: partial (for brevity) JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ..snipped unrelated content

    $('#result').dataTable( { // initialize datatables plugin
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        // ... snipped further initialization parameters of datatables
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {                
            // ...snipped setting GET parameters for AJAX request
            $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            } );
        }
    } );        
} );
```

"result" is a HTML table element in which the data will be displayed.

header and footer.inc.php as requested so it is obvious it is irrelvant to the problem:

```
<!-- start header.inc.php-->
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="../sharedRessources/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">        
        <link href="../sharedRessources/css/datatables/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">               
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../sharedRessources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../sharedRessources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
        <title>myApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="head">
                <h2>myApp</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div id="columns">

<!-- end header.inc.php-->

            <!--page content-->

<!-- start footer.inc.php-->

            <?php
                if (!empty($_SESSION['Message'])) {

                    echo '<div class="message">' . $_SESSION['Message'] . '</div>';
                    unset($_SESSION['Message']);
                }
                if (!empty($_SESSION['Error'])) {

                    echo '<div class="error">' . $_SESSION['Error'] . '</div>';
                    unset($_SESSION['Error']);
                }
            ?>            
            </div>
            <div id="foot">
                <hr>
                <small>Copyright 2011</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- end footer.inc.php-->
```

insertSearchlog.inc.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET)) {

        $searchString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        if (!isset($_SESSION['lastQueryString'])
                || $searchString != $_SESSION['lastQueryString']) {

            $conn = getDatabaseConnection();
            if (!$conn) {
                $e = oci_error();
                trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
            }
            $sqlLog = "INSERT INTO log_table (user_id,search_string) VALUES(:userId,:searchString)";
            $preparedStatement = oci_parse($conn, $sqlLog);
            oci_bind_by_name($preparedStatement, ':userId', $_SESSION['login']);
            oci_bind_by_name($preparedStatement, ':searchString', $searchString);
            oci_execute($preparedStatement);
            oci_free_statement($preparedStatement);
            oci_close($conn);
            $_SESSION['lastQueryString'] = $searchString;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>This is normal behaviour, what you could do is use jQuery.load() to select only the element you want to include on the page, like so:</strike>

```
$(element).load('page.php div#content')
```

That way, anything in your header or footer won't be called.

Alternatively you can pass a variable to the server through a GET request and only set the headers and footers when the variable is not set: calling this URL for your AJAX requests:

```
'page.php?ajax=true'
```

And then putting this PHP in your AJAX-called pages:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_GET['ajax']) {
    require_once('header.inc.php');
    require_once('insertSearchLog.inc.php');
  }

  // HTML etc...

  if (!isset($_GET['ajax']) {
    require_once('footer.inc.php');
  }
```

Comment: If it is normal, why does it "work as I would hav expected" in IE8? IE8 Bug? I'm still kind of puzzled as why an AJAX call would rerun php script? I thought that the point of AJAX is to not need to do that.

Comment: Also note that the ajax call can return multiple rows and the include seems to be called as many times as there are rows returned even though it is only 1 AJAX request. Also behavior is the same in Firefox 3.6 and 9.0.1.

Comment: Because in jQuery using an AJAX load request automatically returns everything in the <body> tag, my guess is that in earlier versions of IE, it does not do this, instead returning all of the HTML.

Comment: Did you actually try the solution, or just decide to argue against it without seeing if it worked?

Comment: I think he means $_GET['ajax'] and not $_GET('ajax') lol. $_GET is not a function.

Comment: Also without knowing the exact content of the plugin and the script in your .inc.php files, I can't comment on why it runs multiple times.

Comment: header and footer inc are mainly html to fix the 2 column layout and link to JS and css files in html head tag. insertSearchLog.inc.php does an simple insert into database.

Comment: Again you say 'mainly' but we need to know what is in the code. There's no use saying 'it's HTML' because that doesn't say a damn thing about it.

Comment: see opener and I guess you believe me now about it being irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Where is 'insertSearchLog.inc.php' because if that is what is getting repeated, it's probably calling something that is getting passed as an array, maybe a session field or something? In fact, looking at your fix I am certain it will have been because the session wasn't getting updated until after the  session data was changed.

Comment: see opener for code and keep in mind it works correctly without the if in IE8.

Comment: Well if this is true then it can not be anything to do with the PHP code, it is executed on the server and returns the same information regardless of the browser so the only logical conclusion is that it must me something to do with the method used to load the data in the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what it is that you are loading through AJAX, if the PHP script you are calling contains those require lines then they will be called every time you make the AJAX request.

The require_once instruction works at the script level, if you call the script multiple times, the require_once will be called multiple times.

Create a separate script to deal with the AJAX call that doesn't require the logging functionality or pass a variable to the AJAX call that allows the script to decide to require or not based on the presence of this variable.

Comment: The actual data is of course retrieved in a separate script and hence the include should only run exactly once. Since it works as expected in IE8 I assume it is a) an firefox b) jquery or c) datatables issue but haven't found anything here or using google.

Comment: Then I would suggest adding a bit more info. For example, how are you making your Ajax call, there may be something there that is triggering a page reload or something. The more info you provide, the easier it is for people to answer your question.

Comment: I did post that info. ajax call is done by JQuery plugin called datatables.

Comment: Have you checked for JS errors when you load this in either browser? What's the behaviour in Chrome?

Comment: No error (using firebug). Can't test chrome. internal app, must only work with IE8 and Firefox.

Comment: Ok, besides, what I have already presented as an answer and that has been elaborated on the other answer, all I can think is that you still should post the actual JS you are using to call datatables in case there is something missing there. Internet Explorer tends to be very permissive of JS syntax and might be letting some error pass that Firefox wouldn't.

Comment: So you do not agree with Andrew that this is normal behavior?

Comment: I don't really disagree, the problem is that from the data so far, it is not clear: how you are requesting the data and hence, whether there are any issues at that point, or what the script you are calling looks like and so, there is no way to see if the require instruction is there. You also say "seems to be a Firefox issue" and I suggest you stick to the facts to avoid confusion or red herrings.

Comment: See edit in first post. Snipped away some content as it is specific to the plugin and meaningless or confusing if you do not know this plugin.

Comment: ok, the key here, in my opinion is in the script you load on the Ajax call, whatever is on sSource and whether that file is requiring your logging or not. In theory, the only way the Log script would be called once per row is if datatables requested it, effectively, once per row. Unless you have concrete proof this should affect both browsers in the same way.